# SignalR with ASP.NET Core doesnt use websockets but long polling

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, asp.net-core

I have just done simple test with ASP.NET Core and SignalR(I used this version - 0.1.0-rtm-21431 -https://www.myget.org/feed/aspnetmaster/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server - guess it's the latest version .NET Core supports but when I'm wrong correct me) and noticed that it's using long polling(i sniffed http requests using Charles).

I did the same test for ASP.NET 4.6.1 with SignalR 2.2.1 - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/ and it uses WebSockets fine.

I noticed that with long polling my test application is clearly slower, sometimes there are differences between clients.

Any idea why SignalR for AspNetCore doesnt use WebSockets but long polling instead? Is that my configuration mistake or maybe SignalR for .NET Core doesn't support websockets yet?

Comment: Which OS are you running it on?

Comment: Did you install/enable websocket in IIS?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/blob/dev/samples/SignalRSample.Web/Startup.cs#L25 for enabling Websockets, though they are not supported on any OS, so it still may fall back to long polling if you run on certain OS'es

Comment: @Tseng, referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets` and then `app.UseWebSockets()` helped! Thank you! However I don't know why I can't reference version `0.2.0-*` of `SignalR.Server` and `WebSockets.Server`. The lates version I can see are `0.1.0` for `WebSockets` and `0.1.0-rtm-21431` for `SignalR`.

Comment: That's because 0.1.0 is the only version which works with ASP.NET Core 1.0.0. The 0.2.* version uses nightly builds of ASP.NET Core 1.1. But unless you are developing an library or extension for ASP.NET Core, i wouldn't suggest using the nightly builds. They break easily when part of the libraries is built and others not yet or require using and installing nightly versions of .NET Core runtime/SDK too SignalR 3 is not ready for release yet, it it's quite more like "alpha" than anything else

Comment: I should have linked to the 1.0.0 branch rather than dev one, which is based around nightlies https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/tree/1.0.0/samples/SignalRSample.Web

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to use websockets you need to enable the websockets middleware first.

From official [SignalR sample](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/blob/1.0.0/samples/SignalRSample.Web/Startup.cs#L25):

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);

        app.UseFileServer();

        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.UseSignalR<RawConnection>("/raw-connection");
        app.UseSignalR();
    }
```

Though websockets are not supported on every OS (Win8 or higher required or Windows Server 2012 or 2008 R2 and higher), so they still may fall back to long polling.

As of the time of writing, the only compatible version that can be used with ASP.NET Core 1.0.0 is `0.1.0-rtm-21431`.

All newer versions are built against the ASP.NET Core nightly builds, which also require nightly versions of .NET Core runtime/SDK. It's not recommended to use the nightly builds, unless you are writing some libraries for ASP.NET Core 1.1, as the nightly builds break often due to incomplete package builds and requirement of latest .NET Core runtimes.

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, outside of IIS. WebSockets works everywhere. The implementation doesn't rely on windows (since .NET Core *is* cross platform)

Comment: @davidfowl: Thanks for the info. So when hosting ASP.NET Core with IIS as reverse proxy the OS limitation still apply, even when using the `app.UseWebSockets()` middleware?

Comment: Yes. Because you need the version of IIS that supports an opaque upgrades, only windows >= 8 gives you that.

Comment: So, if I host my ASP.NET Core 1.1 app within IIS8+ must I install WebSockets feature if IIS?